# CRUD operation necessarily on multiple check boxes

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I am newbie in asp.net mvc core and want to do the crud operation on check-boxes using the entity framework in asp.net core mvc . I had done the crud operation for text boxes but facing the problem for multiple check boxes so can you provide me the link which will teach step by step implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just create `<input type="checkbox" />` and use tag helper `asp-for` to bind it to the properties from your `View Model`.

### View Model

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DL.SO.Project.Reporting.Accounts
{
    public class LoginViewModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    }
}
```

### Controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using DL.SO.Project.Reporting.Accounts;

namespace DL.SO.Project.Web.UI.Controllers
{
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public IActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            var vm = new LoginViewModel
            {
                ReturnUrl = returnUrl,
                // Default the checkbox to checked
                RememberMe = true
            };

            return View(vm);
        }
    }
}
```

### Razor View (Using Bootstrap 4.0 CSS framework)

```
@model DL.SO.Project.Reporting.Accounts.LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Login";
}

<form asp-area="" asp-controller="account" asp-action="login">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="ReturnUrl" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Username" class="required"></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="Username" autofocus="autofocus" />
        <span class="form-text" asp-validation-for="Username"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="Password" class="required"></label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" asp-for="Password" autocomplete="off" />
        <span class="form-text" asp-validation-for="Password"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <!--
            This is how you bind the property "RememberMe" from the 
            view model to the input
        -->
        <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">               
            <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" asp-for="RememberMe" />
            <label asp-for="RememberMe" class="custom-control-label"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Login</button>
</form>
```